# Hibernate schema generation: same configurations, different behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am working on a project and have encountered a quite baffling issue.

Some context: the project is a fairly standard Java 7 project using Maven 3.0.4 as build tool and spring (3.2.3.RELEASE) for dependency injection. Hibernate (4.1.12.Final) is used for persistence.

When running persistence related unit tests (that are using Spring's AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests) the schema is created in a temporary database created only for the tests (using hibernate's hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update property).

This all works great on my development machine (Linux Mint 12).
However when running the exact same code on my laptop (recent install of Linux Mint 15), I observe that Hibernate is **not creating any foreign keys**.

This is especially strange since:

- I am running the exact same software (identical checkout) built from scratch (cleared .m2 repo)
- using the exact same Maven version (3.0.4)
- with identical Spring and Hibernate versions (since these are configured in the maven build configuration checked out with the sourcecode)
- using practically identical Postgresql databases (package version 9.1.9-0ubuntu11.10 on working machine, 9.1.9-1ubuntu1 on laptop), which have the exact same configuration (apart from locale settings)
- database is accessed using the postgres super user, so permissions aren't a problem

Normally I'm pretty good at getting to the root of any weird problems, but this is absolutely baffling me. I can't see any relevant differences that could cause this ...
Any leads on how to find the cause of this would be greatly appreciated!

I can see 2 possible leads for this problem:

- I fiddled around a bit with locales on the laptop, could this somehow cause this problem?
- In the Hibernate properties you will find below, you can see the PostgreSQL82Dialect is used. I have found [this Hibernate forum thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2423458) which mentions the following:

> I saw you're using ProgressDialect and this dialect does not support altering of tables (ProgressDialect.hasAlterTable() returns false).

This seems like the best probably cause for this issue, however then I can still not understand why it works on one setup and not on the other, since the Hibernate configuration is identical on both...

**Some extra information:**

Hibernate configuration (although this is identical on both setups!):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="jpaPersistenceUnitManager" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="hibernateJpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/ehcache-unity-persistence.xml</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Feel free to request more info if you think it could help!
Or if you would like me to check / try something, let me know!

This is really annoying me!

Comment: I'm not sure, but how about checking the log? You will get valuable information there

Comment: You can enable Hibernate log and check if there's anything unusual

Comment: Have no idea. But, maybe you can use ShemaExporter to export your database update to a .sql file and see this issue persists. If yes, you can put some break points on Hiberante source code and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the tip from Hoàng Long to look at the logs led me to the answer:
Apparently my database was just corrupt.

Everything would work perfectly, except the 'ALTER TABLE' statements used to create the foreign key restraints, which would fail with an error.

Apparently my postgresql installation was screwed up...